# Tinymce filenaming causes images to be overwritten when saved

Tags: tinymce

Using TinyMce editor on a PHP-project for creating worklogs. The user can take a screenshot (ex greenshot, snipping tool) and paste this into the Tinymce editor. Tinymce will name the screenshot mceclip0.png (**pic1**), mceclip1.png (**pic2**) etc. The user saves the worklog and the images is uploaded to a folder on webserver with those names. So far so good.

When the user want to edit this worklog later and paste in a new image he/she forgot to add, this image will be name... mceclip0.png (**pic3**). If the user then saves this, oh oh, the first image from the first initial creating of the worklog will be overwritten. So pic1 will now look the same as pic3.

**Here is when the first two pictures are added:**
[image]

**And then the user wants to add a third picture, this happens:**
[image]

Below is the code that is used and from Tinymce. I've tried to change parameters according to documentation with no luck. Some say this is solved by

```
images_reuse_filename: true
```

But this is not the case for me. If I take a snipping tool of something and save it to disk it will be named "screenshot.png". In the Tinymce editor it changes to mceclip0.png anyways.

I was thinking I want to append date and time to the "mceclip.png" name, but I can't figure out how to do so. Would this be a solution?

Thanks in advance!

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    height: 600,
    plugins: 'image code paste',
    paste_data_images: true,
    image_file_types: 'jpg,webp,png',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | link image | code',
    automatic_uploads: true,
    images_upload_url: 'fileUpload.php',
    images_reuse_filename: true,

    images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
        var xhr, formData;
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.open('POST', 'fileUpload');
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var json;

            if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                return;
            }
            json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            if (!json || typeof json.location != 'string') {
                failure('Invalid JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                return;
            }
            success(json.location);
        };
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
        xhr.send(formData);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is no way of changing the filename since it is a blob and set in clipboard.js in the TinyMce-plugin if I understand this correctly. Meaning the only way this is solvable (as far as I can see) is to change this serverside. I created then just a concatenation of unix timestamp and the filename to make it unique.

Now the user can go back and edit the worklogs, adding screenshots without overwriting existing screenshots.